# How to override default browser undo action

Tags: javascript, undo

I've implemeted an undo manager.
The trouble is when the page contains an input text

```
<script>
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
        case 26:
            if (event.shiftKey && event.ctrlKey) {
                // Ctrl+Shift+z
                redo();
            }
            else if (event.ctrlKey) {
                // Ctrl+z
                undo();
            }
            break;
        }
    })
</script>
<input type="text">
```

Then, when input text is edited, if I trigger an undo event by typing Ctrl+z, the input text is undone without my undo manager is called.

I would like to force the browser to call my undo manager on Ctrl+z, even when the page contains text field or text area.

Comment: can you do a `event.preventDefault()` before calling your function?

Comment: Ah I said, the manager is not called at all on Ctrl+z, so event.preventDefault is also not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the `keydown` event rather than `keypress`. The browser undo triggers on keydown, but keypress doesn't occur until the key has been lifted up. Additionally, if you don't want the browser to do its own undo, you need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```
<script>
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
    case 90:
        if (event.shiftKey && event.ctrlKey) {
            // Ctrl+Shift+z
            event.preventDefault();
            redo();
        }
        else if (event.ctrlKey) {
            // Ctrl+z
            event.preventDefault();
            undo();
        }
        break;
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution is not working. Keydown is called immediatly after Ctrl is pressed, so Ctrl+z is not intercepted.

Comment: Well, in your example you were looking for "case 26" which I assumed was the "z" key, but it's actually 90. 26 doesn't actually map to any key. I've updated my answer with the correct key code.